SIGSEGV blender
I get this error:
Writing: /tmp/the_adv.crash.txt
Neoprávněný přístup do paměti (SIGSEGV) (core dumped [obraz paměti uložen])

In english I think it means
Writing: /tmp/the_adv.crash.txt
Unauthorized memory access (SIGSEGV) (core dumped [memory image saved])

I only gget this error only when using Blender.
I'm using ubuntu 24.10 but I've had this error on older versions as well.

File a bug with blender. This is a memory access error. (Blender code tries to access memory it is not supposed to)
